# Primefaces 10 dataexport with subtable not working

Tags: primefaces, data-export

After we switched to Primefaces 10, the data export from a table with a subtable no longer works. Does anyone have a similar problem or solution?
Our goal is to download the table with the subtable in an Excel file.

Sourcecode:

```
                 <p:splitButton
                        id="submitButtonId"
                        value="#{msg.global_button_search}"
                        update="table"
                        icon="#{style.global_icon_search}"
                        actionListener="#{appointment.loadEvents}"
                        styleClass="MarTop10">
                    <p:menuitem
                            value="#{msg.global_button_exportExcel}"
                            icon="#{style.global_icon_excel} splittIcon"
                            id="xls"
                            ajax="false">
                        <p:dataExporter
                                type="xlsxstream"
                                target="table"
                                fileName="Terminueberwachung" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                    <p:menuitem
                            value="#{msg.global_button_exportPdf}"
                            icon="#{style.global_icon_pdf} splittIcon"
                            id="pdf"
                            ajax="false">
                        <p:dataExporter
                                type="pdf"
                                target="table"
                                fileName="Terminueberwachung"/>
                    </p:menuitem>
                </p:splitButton>
```

Comment: You can report PrimeFaces issues here https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: DataExporter was heavily refactored but I don't remember it ever supporting SubTable?

Comment: Are you sure this worked in previous PF versions I am looking through the Exporter source code and Subtable is not handled anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces Extensions had the subTable option and it was removed in favour of Primefaces 10. So expectably, Primefaces should cover all it's functionality, but in this case, it doesn't.